# Where are users of Ethereum 2.0 located?

Tags: eth-2.0

I was going through some caracteristics of Ethereum 2.0 for research purposes and I couldn't quite figure out where the users are located ?

As I understand, a validator is registered on the beacon chain and dispatched to a shard / committee to validate that given shard right ? (A validator is also able to validate both the beacon chain and a shard). Are simple users also assigned to shards knowingly or not ? or are they broadcasting to the beacon chain that will divide the transactions set as well as the validators and dispatch it in the different shards ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This question is quite confusing. Are you looking for the geographic location for the users of the network or for the validators in the network? Are you looking to understand how sharding works? Sharding is still a research topic that has not been implemented yet.